# How to remove/delete last character from printed list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, character, separator

I am creating simple program which finds the smallest multiplicators of a number (not sure if this is the right term). However, I can not find a way to delete last "*" from the listed result. What am I doing wrong? Please help.

```
num = int(input("write number: "))
print(num, end = "=")
div = 2
while num > 1:
    if num % div == 0:
        num = num / div
        print(div, end = "*")
    else:
        div += 1
```

Result I got:

```
24=2*2*2*3*
```

Result I want:

```
24=2*2*2*3
```

I tried to use sep="*" instead of end="*", tried \b, [:-1] but this does not work or I am just doing it wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is simply to check whether or not num =1 before printing the "*"

```
num = num / div
if num == 1 :
    print(div)
else :
    print(div, end = "*")
```

Since you only want to print a * if there are more multipliers to come, and there will always be another multiplier if div is more than 1.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list of divisors and then print the concatenated list.

```
num = int(input("write number: "))
print(num, end = "=")
div = 2
out = []
while num > 1:
    if num % div == 0:
        num = num / div
        out.append(div)
    else:
        div += 1
print('*'.join(map(str,out)))
```

Test:

```
write number: 24
24=2*2*2*3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate your results:

```
s += div + "*"
```

And after just don't print last symbol:

```
print(s[:-1])
```

But in my mind it's a bad decision because in python type string is immutable type --> and because of it every time "s += div + "*"" new variable "s" will be created.

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('\b \b') ##at the end of the program
```

result:

```
write number: 24
24=2*2*2*3
```